# Issue Linking Box2D application on OS X

Tags: c++, box2d, sdl

I have an SDL game I have been working on as my first somewhat real project. I decided to introduce Box2D physics as I was not happy with the collision detection. So I installed it to /usr/local/lib/Box2D and in the folder is Box2D.h and supporting folders. I am using MacVim to code on OSX 10.9.2 to develop, and clang++ compiler from the command line.

In my game code I am just trying to create a simple world to test things out:

```
#include <Box2D/Box2D.h>
.......
world = new b2World(b2Vec2(0.0,9.81));
```

My make command finds the library, but errors out trying to build.

```
$ make clean && make
rm -rf obj bin
clang++ -Wall -c -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/lib src/Ball.cpp -o obj/Ball.o
clang++ -Wall -c -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/lib src/Game.cpp -o obj/Game.o
clang++ -Wall -c -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/lib src/Paddle.cpp -o obj/Paddle.o
clang++ -Wall -c -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/lib src/TextureManager.cpp -o obj/TextureManager.o
clang++ -Wall -c -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/lib src/main.cpp -o obj/main.o
clang++ -framework SDL2 -framework SDL2_image -F /Library/Frameworks -L/usr/local/lib/Box2D    obj/Ball.o   obj/Game.o   obj/Paddle.o   obj/TextureManager.o   obj/main.o -o bin/game 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "b2World::b2World(b2Vec2 const&)", referenced from:
      Game::init() in Game.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [game] Error 1
```

And here is my Makefile. Box2D is in /usr/local/lib/Box2D/Box2D.h. I am pretty sure my issue is somewhere in the Makefile.

```
CXX = clang++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -c -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/lib

SDL = -framework SDL2 -framework SDL2_image
LDFLAGS = $(SDL) -F /Library/Frameworks -L/usr/local/lib/Box2D

SRC_DIR = src
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)

OBJ_DIR = obj
OBJECTS = $(subst $(SRC_DIR)/, $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SOURCES)))
#$(warning $(OBJECTS))

BIN_DIR = bin
EXE = game

# run these no matter what
.PHONY: all clean run

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJECTS)
    @mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$(EXE) 

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf obj bin

run:
    ./$(BIN_DIR)/$(EXE)
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that you ever actually *link* the Box2D library anywhere? You use `-L` to specify directories to search while linking, but I don't see a `-l` option to actually link the Box2D library (whatever it's called).

Your output line seems to bear this out:

```
clang++ -framework SDL2 -framework SDL2_image -F /Library/Frameworks -L/usr/local/lib/Box2D    obj/Ball.o   obj/Game.o   obj/Paddle.o   obj/TextureManager.o   obj/main.o -o bin/game
```

You need to get `-lbox2d` (or whatever the correct name for the Box2D library is) in there.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Your answer lead me to read more on linking and I am pretty sure I skipped a rather crucial step. Building Box2D before linking it. I'm pretty new to C++ as should be obvious by now :) I'll come back and update once I figure that out.